How to transfer imagebutton to another imagebutton in Android studio in Java?
I want to write a game similar to Alchemy with themes from the animated series. I wrote the code and found the part of the code I needed using libgdx, but this is only part of what I need. There should be a move of the imagebutton from one table to another small one, where a new element will be created. Tell me what needs to be done or what information to look for.
enter image description here
enter image description here
